# why pipe symbol in python adds to integer?

Tags: python, pipe

when I do the following in python shell !

```
>> print 2 | 4
>> 6
```

why pipe symbol in python adds to integer ?

Comment: Because it's not a pipe : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a pipe symbol, it is a **bitwise OR**.

```
2 in binary:    10
4 in binary:   100
__________________
with or:       110  (1 or 0: 1, 1 or 0: 1, 0 or 0: 0)
```

And 110 in binary is 6 decimal.

Answer (score 2):

It's not addition. It's a bitwise OR. 2 and 4 just happen to be `010` and `100` in binary, so both their sum and their OR is `110` (6).

More info and examples at https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score 1):

The pipe symbol stands for `bitwise OR` in python.
Since `bin(2) == '0b10'`, `bin(4) == '0b100'` and `bin(6) = '0b110'`, you can see that `2 | 4` actually did a `bitwise OR`.